# why was my answer to a question got deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I am curious why my answer was deleted to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java)? Looking at the FAQ section, I do not see which one it falls under. I was the first to answer so it can't be that my answer is too similar to others.

If someone could explain the rationale I would really appreciate it!

> deleted by Robert Harvey♦ 28 mins ago
>   Why was your post deleted? See the
>   faq.

Here is the content of my answer:-

> You definitely can switch on enums. An
>   example posted from the java
>   [tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).
>
> ```
> public enum Day {
>     SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, 
>     THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
>  }
>
> public class EnumTest {
>     Day day;
>
> public EnumTest(Day day) {
>     this.day = day;
> }
>
> public void tellItLikeItIs() {
>     switch (day) {
>         case MONDAY: System.out.println("Mondays are bad.");
>                      break;
>
>         case FRIDAY: System.out.println("Fridays are better.");
>                      break;
>
>         case SATURDAY:
>         case SUNDAY: System.out.println("Weekends are best.");
>                      break;
>
>         default:     System.out.println("Midweek days are so-so.");
>                      break;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: For those who can't see deleted posts, what was the content of your answer? If it's a long one, just the gist would suffice.

Comment: Sure I will add it.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I don't know and I'm only speculating, but if I had to guess it's either a) due to the code sample you pasted not being Fair Use or b) the manner in which you provided it (a link and a paste) wasn't really an answer. Both however, are prevalent in the other answers: you might've just been the unlucky one to receive a flag.

Comment: @Mark Trapp - well, that sounds fair (about being unlucky). However, I think it should be treated fairly across the board. I can easily remove the code section & replace with my own code or just remove it all together. I would like to understand the reason so that I don't have to repeat this myself.

Comment: coming to meta helps. I just gave you an upvote to compensate for the missed upvotes :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can not tell you why Robert deleted this, I do not know.

But I went ahead and undeleted. Nonetheless, the question itself is a train-wreck it is 2 hours old, with 4 duplicate answers.

I try to avoid adding an answer unless my answer is going to add something materially new to the question, it appears that in this question people are more focused at getting rep, than creating a resource that others can easily consume.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I know the answers got duplicated but I was the first to answer so to be fair I could not have known. However, I do see your point about the question being a _train-wreck_. I personally think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391777/switch-on-enum-in-java/6391821#6391821) was the best answer and I upvoted it as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you another reason why...

Betcha somebody flagged as "not a real answer."  A casual glimpse would tend to support this.  Your answer is riding the line between what can be considered an answer and what should be just a comment.  One mod might let it stand, another might convert it to a comment, and another might delete it.  Its not the best situation, but that's what happens in grey areas--we make a call based on our best judgement.

Answers should, hypothetically, stand on their own.  A better version of your answer would include more than one line.  An example would have been great, rather than *just* pointing to an example on a different site.

Comment: The answer includes the code sample from the tutorial, so I'm not sure what the issue was. One person flagged as not an answer and another flagged the first as invalid.

Comment: @mmyers: Crap, I misunderstood the break in the quoted text.  My whole answer is invalid.  Please delete it kthx.